# Make a 9v battery power USB powered light?

Tags: voltage, batteries, resistors, usb, voltage-regulator

I am somewhat of a noob to electric circuits. I bought a USB powered light off ebay for fun [(link to the item)](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=usb%20flexible%20led&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xusb%20miniflexible%20led.TRS1&_nkw=usb%20mini%20flexible%20led&_sacat=0), and I want to somehow make it powered off a 9v battery instead of a computer. I understand that I am going to need some kind of resistor to drop the voltage, but I am not sure what kind to get, and if that is the only thing I must do. I have access to many tools and electic stuff, so no worries there. I am basically asking what parts I need to do this and how to hook it up? Thanks!

Comment: A standard rectangular 9v battery isn't going to power a light very long.  You're better off using three 1.5 AA cells in series (which will be a little dimmer).  A 9V alkaline battery has about 560 mAh; an AA alkaline cell has 2700 mAh, almost 5 times as much.  And you won't need any voltage converter (a simple resistor is not a good idea).

Comment: Wait so 3 AA batteries will put out enough volts to power the USB port? And all I have to do is connect them end to end and wire up the rest?  Thanks!

Comment: Could I just use one of these to hold the batteries? http://i.imgur.com/puhAvNx.png

Comment: They'll put out 4.5V.  Since the light is supposed to be "super bright" I'm guessing it will still be bright enough.  Won't hurt to try.  That holder will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

To power a 5 V device (LED lamp) with a 9 V battery, you need to look at the following:

1. The LED's current consumption at 5 V.
2. How long do you want to run the lamp ? This will determine the current rating of the battery you would need.

eg: If the consumption is 200 mA at 5 V and you want to run this for 5 hours the total charge would be 1000 mAH ([milliampere hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere-hour)). You would then need a battery which is 5 V, 1000 mAH. The total supplied power is 5 Watts.

Now coming to your requirement of 9 V battery. 
You would need a voltage converter (ideally a [Buck regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter)) which can convert 9 V to 5 V at 200 mA. Choose a converter for about 500 mA for getting the max efficiency. Take 90 % efficiency for this conversion.

So, about 0.6 ~ 0.7 (750 mAh) battery would do. Try putting AAA cells. preferably. NiMH (if you want to charge them again). Please see that NiMH cells are 1.2V instead of 1.5V for regular cells.

If you are still intending to use 9 V (6F22) batteries, you might want to put more than one battery in parallel.

Also watch out for the economics as the 9V batteries aren't that cheap !

Answer (score 0):

Ranjan, your answer is perfect. But probably we can also get a little easier solution.

- Use 4.5V batteries. Get a 3xAA or 3xAAA battery holder like this: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10891
- grab an USB extension cable like this: [http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-USB-Extension-Cable-10-Feet/dp/B00001ZWXA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00001ZWXA)
- connect your USB lamp to the extension cable
- cut the USB extension cable, so you have access to the wires. Throw away the part which normally goes to the computer, you'll replace that with the battery.
- connect the black and red wires from the battery pack to the black and red wires to the cable
- it is a good idea to insulate the other two wires separately
- put the batteries in, switch it on, and you're golden.

If you really want to use 9V battery, that is not the best choice. Unless you can really use a switching mode buck regulator as suggested by @Ranjan, there is a serious waste of the energy.

- The simplest solution is to use a 7805 linear regulator, instead of resistors. This ensures that you get a stable 5V from any input of around 7..30V. This is one component, and you don't need anything else.
- Connect the 9V battery clip to the regulator, and the output of the regulator is a stable 5V so you can connect the USB cable there.
- You can follow this instructable: http://www.instructables.com/id/Portable-USB-Charger-Version-2.0/ (feel free to ignore the capacitors in your use case).

Comment: Good stuff, but I have seen that some cheap USB cables do not follow the red/black standard, they have red/black wires but they are not hooked up to the correct pins. So maybe something on how to test it if this is the case. I was quite confused for a while when I first found this.